# How can I purge old kernel packages in Elementary OS?

Tags: linux-kernel, dpkg

On my Elementary OS system, dpkg reports a number of kernel packages that aren't installed. (I did an apt-get purge on them previously.) I'd like to have them forgotten about entirely, but I can't figure out how to get them that way.

For example:

```
elementary:~$ dpkg -l linux-*-3.2.0-51*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                              Description
+++-====================================-====================================-========================================================================================
un  linux-headers-3.2.0-51               <none>                               (no description available)
un  linux-headers-3.2.0-51-generic       <none>                               (no description available)
un  linux-image-3.2.0-51-generic         <none>                               (no description available)
```

apt-get purge doesn't work:

```
elementary:~$ sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.2.0-51
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package linux-headers-3.2.0-51 is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

dpkg doesn't work:

```
elementary:~$ sudo dpkg --purge linux-headers-3.2.0-51
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching linux-headers-3.2.0-51
elementary:~$ sudo dpkg --forget-old-unavail
dpkg: warning: obsolete '--forget-old-unavail' option, unavailable packages are automatically cleaned up.
```

apt-cache shows:

```
elementary:~$ apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.2.0-51
linux-headers-3.2.0-51:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.2.0-51.77
  Version table:
     3.2.0-51.77 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
```

aptitude isn't installed.

Obviously, there's something I'm not understanding. Why does dpkg -l show purged packages? How do I go about making dpkg forget about them?

Comment: Does your `dpkg` still have a `--forget-old-unavail`?

Comment: @derobert Unfortunately not. I added the result to the question.

Comment: Well, I guess the next thing to check is `apt-cache policy linux-headers-3.2.0-51` to make sure the package is actually unavailable.

Comment: @derobert I added that to the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `apt-cache policy` output, they're still in the archive (aka available), so dpkg won't forget about them. So the short answer is there isn't a way to get rid of that record.

The long answer is you could probably edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status` (it's a plain-text file) to do it. Make sure to keep a backup. Breaking this file would not be a good thing, badness level approaching "have you considered re-installing?"

Comment: /var/lib/dpkg/status doesn't contain the string "3.2.0-51". Or -52, or -53. Heh. I'm beginning to think that dpkg is a bit sloppy.

Comment: Then it must be `/var/lib/dpkg/available`, which is going to get updated with apt-get update. Problem is, its a package that your distro (Ubuntu) is giving out—that's why dpkg knows about it.

Comment: If Ubuntu is pushing the dpkg data at me willy-nilly, I guess I'll just have to learn to live with dead kernel package names in the list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dpkg --clear-avail` to delete dpkgs available packge list.